# Excel auto incremental number in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to make a formula that has a number in it which I would like to be auto incremented once I hold and drag the formula along a row.

For example my formula (simplified) is:

```
=500 + 1
```

And if I try to hold and drag the formula from A1 along the row, the formula will remain the same. But I would like to indicate that the number 1 should is an incremental value (without introducing any new row with data). So the result I'm trying to achieve will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using my version of Excel 2013 (prior and later compatibility will need to be verified), if I input "500" in `A1` and I input `=A1 + 1` in `B1` and then drag across columns, it will not increment the number (`1`) but the cell reference (`A1`) and will yield the result you are after I believe:

```
Cell A1 Will be "500"
Cell B1 will be "=A1 + 1"
Cell C1 will be "=B1 + 1"
```

And so on.

Comment: FYI It should be moving across columns, not rows

Comment: @PeterH It works either ways but I corrected my example to reflect OP's use case, thanks for noting it!

Comment: Cool nice answer +1 !

Answer (score 2):

Put this in A1:

```
=500 + COLUMN(A1)
```

And drag across.

Or put 501 in A1 and in B1 put:

```
=A1 + 1
```

And drag across

The relative reference will update as it is drug across adding 1 more to  the previous cell.